# RPS game does not work/ the score display and result display

Tags: javascript

I have been working on his Rock Paper scissors game for a bit too long and I am stuck. For some reason, the result does not display either the scoreboard I have made. What can I do to fix it?

HTML part

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<h2>Computer-choice:<span id="computer-choice"></span></h2>
<h2>User choice:<span id="user-choice"></span></h2>
<h2>Result:<span id="Result"></span></h2>
<h2>Computer score:<span id="Computer-Score"></span></h2>
<h2>Player score:<span id="Player-Score"></span></h2>


<button id="rock">rock</button>
<button id="paper">paper</button>
<button id="scissors">scissors</button>

<script src="RPSreload.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript part

```
const computerChoiceDisplay = document.getElementById(`computer-choice`)
const userChoiceDisplay = document.getElementById(`user-choice`)
const possibleChoices= document.querySelectorAll(`button`)
const playerScoreDisplay= document.getElementById('Player-Score')
const computerScoreDisplay= document.getElementById('Computer-Score')
const displayResult= document.getElementById('Result')

let PlayerChoice
let computerChoice

possibleChoices.forEach ( possibleChoices => possibleChoices.addEventListener(`click`, (e) =>{
    userChoice=e.target.id
    userChoiceDisplay.innerHTML = userChoice
    computerPlay()
    getResult();
   }));
   
function computerPlay(){

const randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1

if (randomNumber === 1){
    computerChoice = 'rock'
} 
if (randomNumber === 2){
    computerChoice = 'paper'
}
if (randomNumber === 3){
    computerChoice = 'scissors'
}
computerChoiceDisplay.innerHTML= computerChoice;
};


function getResult(){

  
    let result=""

let ComputerScore= 0;
let PlayerScore= 0;

 
if((PlayerChoice ==='rock' && computerChoice==='scissors') ||
(PlayerChoice ==='scissors'&& computerChoice==='paper') ||
(PlayerChoice ==='paper' && computerChoice==='rock')){

    PlayerScore=+1
    result='You win!'
};
if(PlayerScore == 5){
result='You won the game!';
disableButtons()
} else{ ComputerScore=+1
}

if(ComputerScore == 5){
result='The computer has won!'
disableButtons();
}

displayResult.innerHTML=result;
computerScoreDisplay.innerHTML=ComputerScore;
playerScoreDisplay.innerHTML=PlayerScore;
};

function disableButtons() {
    buttons.forEach(elem => {
        elem.disabled = true
    })
}
```

I have been trying to make a separate function CheckWin where I would check if the result is "You win/You lose" and based on that make the ComputerScore/PlayerScore work on that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a more useful title, and use the preview code block (preferably without styling / with minimal styling), so we can answer your question more effectively. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We could use your HTML as well, in order to help

Comment: I think you can see he html part now try to refresh the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were few things that were wrong with your code:-

- You were declaring `ComputerScore` and `PlayerScore` inside `getResult()` function. So these variables were declared again, on each function call. You need to declare them in global scope.
- In the event listener, you were using `userChoice` variable, whereas the actual variable is `PlayerChoice`.
- While incrementing the player score (and computer score), you were doing `PlayerScore=+1`, which will set the player score to 1, not increase it. You need to do `PlayerScore += 1` to increase it.
- You need to write some if conditions to handle 'draw' and 'computer win'. Also, the `else` part where you increase computer score does not belong to above if condition.

  ```js
  const computerChoiceDisplay = document.getElementById(`computer-choice`)
  const userChoiceDisplay = document.getElementById(`user-choice`)
  const possibleChoices = document.querySelectorAll(`button`)
  const playerScoreDisplay = document.getElementById('Player-Score')
  const computerScoreDisplay = document.getElementById('Computer-Score')
  const displayResult = document.getElementById('Result')

  let PlayerChoice
  let computerChoice

  let ComputerScore = 0;
  let PlayerScore = 0;

  possibleChoices.forEach(possibleChoice => possibleChoice.addEventListener(`click`, (e) => {
    PlayerChoice = e.target.id
    userChoiceDisplay.innerHTML = PlayerChoice
    computerPlay()
    getResult();
  }));

  function computerPlay() {

    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1

    if (randomNumber === 1) {
      computerChoice = 'rock'
    }
    if (randomNumber === 2) {
      computerChoice = 'paper'
    }
    if (randomNumber === 3) {
      computerChoice = 'scissors'
    }
    computerChoiceDisplay.innerHTML = computerChoice;
  };


  function getResult() {


    let result = ""

    if ((PlayerChoice === 'rock' && computerChoice === 'scissors') ||
      (PlayerChoice === 'scissors' && computerChoice === 'paper') ||
      (PlayerChoice === 'paper' && computerChoice === 'rock')) {

      PlayerScore += 1
      result = 'You win!'
    };
    if (PlayerScore == 5) {
      result = 'You won the game!';
      disableButtons()
    } else {
      ComputerScore += 1
    }

    if (ComputerScore == 5) {
      result = 'The computer has won!'
      disableButtons();
    }

    displayResult.innerHTML = result;
    computerScoreDisplay.innerHTML = ComputerScore;
    playerScoreDisplay.innerHTML = PlayerScore;
  };

  function disableButtons() {
    possibleChoices.forEach(elem => {
      elem.disabled = true
    })
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Computer-choice:<span id="computer-choice"></span></h2>
    <h2>User choice:<span id="user-choice"></span></h2>
    <h2>Result:<span id="Result"></span></h2>
    <h2>Computer score:<span id="Computer-Score"></span></h2>
    <h2>Player score:<span id="Player-Score"></span></h2>


    <button id="rock">rock</button>
    <button id="paper">paper</button>
    <button id="scissors">scissors</button>

    <script src="RPSreload.js"></script>
  </body>

  </html>
  ```